# I need to organize a string in an ascending form but im not sure what is the error

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm trying to organize a string but my code fails. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or even if my code is close to what I'm trying to do.

```
void ordenar(int lengh, char string[])
{
    char aux[20];

    for (int i = 0; i < lengh; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengh; j++){
            if (strcmp(string[j], string[i] > 0)) {
                strcpy(aux, string[i]);
                strcpy(string[i], string[j]);
                strcpy(string[j], aux);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char nombre_prueba[10] = "Leandro";

    ordenar(7, nombre_prueba);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%s",nombre_prueba);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I asked a friend to help, but he has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should be issuing some pretty serious diagnostic messages, that you should not be ignoring. If it is quiet, you need need to turn up your compiler warning level:

- For `gcc` or `clang`, use `-Wall -Wextra`
- For `MSVC`, use `/Wall`

---

The [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function takes two *strings* as arguments, as `const char *`. In your code, `string[j]` and `string[i]` are both of type `char`, an integral value representing a single character in the string.

Even if you had two strings to compare, the `> 0` is within the argument list of the function call, which becomes much more clear with better formatting.

```
strcmp(string[j], string[i] > 0)
```

This function is not needed to reorder the contents of a string. With an ASCII encoding, you could compare each character directly.

Note that the `printf` specifier `%s` prints a single string. This call is correct, `printf("%s", nombre_prueba);`, but you are repeating it seven times.

With minimal changes, your code could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ordenar(int lengh, char string[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lengh; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lengh; j++) {
            if (string[j] > string[i]) {
                char t = string[i];
                string[i] = string[j];
                string[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char nombre_prueba[10] = "Leandro";
    ordenar(7, nombre_prueba);
    printf("%s\n", nombre_prueba);
}
```

which prints `Ladenor`. Note that uppercase letters come before lowercase letters in the [ASCII table](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ascii.7.html). This creates a string in [*ASCIIbetical order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order).